# React Router activeStyle return [object object]

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm learning React Router and is testing some codes.  I found that NavLink activeStyle is not working.  I've followed the instructions on StackOverflow, I still get [object object].  My code:

```
class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <p><NavLink to="/" activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>Home</NavLink></p>
                    <p><NavLink to="/Contact" activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>Contact</NavLink></p>
                </nav>

                <h1>Begin</h1>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route exact path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
                </Routes >

                <h1>Middle</h1>
                <p><Link to="/">Home</Link></p>
                <p><Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link></p>

                <h1>End</h1>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

What I see in Inspect is:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you use?

Comment: @Konrad react-router-dom@6.9.0 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` no longer supports `activeStyle` property on `NavLink` component

You should use `style` prop instead:

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  style={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? { backgroundColor: "white" } : undefined
  }
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

The new way of doing this is via prop `style`

```
<NavLink 
   to="/Contact" 
   style={({isActive}) => isActive ? { backgroundColor: "white" } : undefined}
   className={({isActive}) => isActive ? 'active' : ''}
>
   Contact
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see you value-add with how I can make use of isActive in other situations, such as className.  I appreciate this info.  I apologise I didn't check your answer as I've read the other answer first.